# Index_file and kohana 3.1.2

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

Adding `'index_file' => FALSE` to the `Kohana::init` successfully removes the index.php part of URLs, but when a page is redirected to website.com/controller/action (note: there is no index.php before controller) I get a `404 Not Found` error.

How is lighttpd supposed to know to call the index.php file at the base instead of looking for a controller/action folder (which it seems to be doing and thus getting a 404)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use URL rewriting.

I would port Kohana's `.htaccess` [to lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs%3aModRewrite).